# correct arguments format for strtotime

Tags: php, date, time, strtotime

I've been using strtotime("$day-$month-$year"), in my app and it works cool... but know I want to make some date comparisons still in this format but I'm not sure about what is precise,

It's as if any format goes

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [manual page for `strtotime()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strtotime.php) has some good insights, including the comments.

Comment: I'm along those lines now, both formats ("$day-$month-$year") or ("$year-$month-$day") resolve to the same answer. thanks

Comment: `strtotime — Parse about any English textual datetime description into a Unix timestamp` from http://php.net/manual/en/function.strtotime.php. Can you elaborate `about any English textual datetime description` ?